# Is it possible to use variables to access elements in an array (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Or is there any way to get around this? For example is there any way I could make this work (it's from Eloquent Javascript for those who may recognize the problem):

```
    var centuries =  [
      [],[],[],[],[]
    ];


    ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
      var centuryOfDeath =(Math.ceil(person.died /100));
      var centuryArray =(centuryOfDeath - 16);
      centuries[centuryArray].push(person); //Here I am trying to access an element in an array using a variable. I know this doesn't work, but is there a way to make it work?


});
```

Comment: It works `centuries[centuryArray]` or else `centuryArray` is not a integer. Try `parseInt(centuryArray)`

Comment: Thanks, using parseInt() works!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript objects:

```js
people = 
    {
        "mary": "100",
        "george" : "200",
        "ian" : "300",
    }

alert(people["mary"]);
alert(people[prompt("Who?")]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `centuries.indexOf(centuryArray)`

that will either return the index of the value or -1 if it's not found

if centuryArray is already your index and your trying to insert you can use

```
centuries.splice(centuryArray, 1, person)
```